# Using the "X" as a close button vs a button labeled "close window"

Tags: gui-design, button, close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing modal dialogs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/closing-modal-dialogs)

I'm developing a flash application that has buttons that popup a window with more text, and information when they click it. This happens throughout the course.  The close button is a square box with an "X" inside of it. The client upon review stated their review asked us to change it because felt the "X" looks like the page didn't load correctly (old browser can't load image icons??).

I have a strong intuition to stick with the "X" button because I feel it's more recognizable than having a button with "close window" label. Which is the best way to go about this? Also, is the "X" as a close button globally recognizable as a close button?

Comment: Could you post an image/mockup? You are talking about a X in the top right corner of the window, right? Additionally, is there any part of your question *not* answered by the question GotDibbs linked?

Comment: Is the X red?  Otherwise I can't see how there would be any confusion.  Grey is a good color and very clear.

Comment: Sorry, I did a search for the same type of question, but I probably didn't use the right search terms. Thanks for linking to that question @GotDibbs.

Comment: Hawkee, the X is heavy weight with a red square background.

Comment: A couple of advantages I see: 1) When using an icon vs text, you remove the need to internationalize the text. 2) a "X" icon is a known pattern, across operating systems, unless using strange colors or "X" icon, the user will know exactly what it means

Comment: @AdrienBe, thanks for the comment. Yes, I think you're right especially with consideration to translating the text to various languages (which for that project we did).

Answer (score 2):

When closing an informational modal dialog, it's best to provide two methods. OK and the X to close:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzSxjq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If the X is anywhere but the top right (or top left for Mac users), on a red colored background, they will have difficulty finding it or knowing what it is.

One alternative solution I have seen for custom dialogs (Flash, Web overlays), is a [Close X] button.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcoMPu.png)</sup>

This is a bit simpler to implement and uses less space, while still being quite clear to most users. I do not recommend using a red colored X in either case (use a red *background* for the X button), because the user is right; this does hearken back to the 'missing image' icon in Internet explorer, especially if it is not located in the top right corner.

Comment: Honestly Close X would be more confusing to me, as I've been clicking red Xes for years.

Comment: I do prefer red-background-X buttons myself, but I've seen many web overlays move to the [Close X] method. I can see the appeal, though I have not done any user testing myself to confirm. Like any choice, testing is the best answer when you aren't certain... and often when you are.

Answer (score 0):

Which is better depends on your target audience.  It's not clear from the question whether this is designed for a broad consumer audience, or whether it is intended for use within a fairly defined group.  I would argue that the approach differs for each.

For a broad (i.e. global) consumer audience, the x at a top corner is common enough that I doubt it would cause any major confusion.  Although you should remember that it isn't always on the right.  Mac users will be used to having it on the left.  If possible, I would also let the "esc" key act as a close option.  Many people are used to this, and it doesn't complicate your interface at all.

For a closed and fairly well defined group, you have an easy opportunity to find a solid answer to the question with a little testing, so use it.  **Test it** with your potential users and see which is clearer for them and then go with that.